# delphi does not find graphicsd dcu using FM firemonkey framework

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I also suffered the problem given already her [Graphics.dcu issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797138/design-time-package-fails-to-build-file-not-found-graphics-dcu). My unit statement goes like this

```
 uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,  Math,
```

But I have a different issue. Using VCL framework I got no problem, the failure only occurs while using Firemonkey framework with my units.

OS = WIN 7 Prof.
Delphi XE2  Update 4

Comment: have you tried to use the FMX prefix http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Graphics ? which is exact the problem?

Comment: So, did you use namespace prefix like `FMX.Graphics`? Or make sure Fmx is included in the Unit Scope Names list in the Project Options.

Comment: Please show the error message. Perhaps your code uses Graphicsd instead of Graphics. Or perhaps this is a console app with out the unit scope name set for a gui framework.

Answer (score 4):

A few things:

1. While similar, the FireMonkey unit names don't slavishly follow the VCL ones. For extra fun, they can also change from version to version! The core FireMonkey units though are `FMX.Types` (all versions), `FMX.Controls` (XE4+, though it existed previously), `FMX.Forms` (all versions) and `FMX.Graphics` (XE5+).
2. You should always include the unit scope when referencing a FireMonkey unit, so it's `FMX.Forms` not just `Forms`.
3. The uses clause you have quoted appears to be just the default uses clause added to new form units in very early versions of Delphi, plus `Math` (the lack of `Variants` suggests pre-D6!). In practice it is better to only use the units you are actually using symbols from. In particular, if you are really reliant on `Windows` and `Messages`, then you will have issues cross compiling the code with FMX (FMX controls typically don't have an `HWND`, and the FMX `TForm` doesn't support the VCL variant's nifty message handling syntax).