# Is it good practice to exploit a compiler bug?

Tags: delphi

Recently I found some odd-looking (to me) Delphi code and I have isolated it to a separate small project. Here is what I discovered. **Unit1 compiles with no errors**. Unit2 (which I provide for comparison) does not. The difference is in the way that Classes is `used`.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Classes; // difference here

type TThread = class(Classes.TThread)
public
   property Terminated;
end;

implementation

end.
```

Unit2 does not compile. Various errors are produced.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses System.Classes; // difference here

type TThread = class(Classes.TThread)
public
  property Terminated;
end;

implementation

end.

[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(7): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Classes'
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(7): E2029 ',' or ':' expected but ')' found
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(9): E2147 Property 'Terminated' does not exist in base class
```

***So my concern is that this project is exploiting a compiler bug to achieve it's goals***. The compiler bug might be fixed in a later release, and then the code won't work anymore.

Comment: Of course it is bad practice to use a compiler bug. But that is not what is going on here. What version of Delphi are you using, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Dsm. It's Delphi 10.0 and Delphi 10.1 (both, the same) I have edited the question to include the error messages for Unit2. There are no errors for Unit1 and Unit3.

Comment: I cannot see a compiler bug here. The code of Unit2 is just wrong, while the code of Unit1 relies on the correct setting of unit scope names.

Comment: @UweRaabe. In what way is unit2's code wrong?

Comment: @nolaspeaker: if the uses contains the fully qualified `System.Classes`, then it must be used like that in the rest of the unit too, so `Classes.TThread` must be fully qualified as `System.Classes.TThread`. FWIW, I'd rather do something like: `TFetchMessageThread = class(TThread)`.

Comment: True. The new TThread class really should have a better name.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797352/988445

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no compiler bug that makes Unit1 compile. It compiles because in the project setting the entry for Unit Scope Names contains at least the item *System*, which is used to resolve the reference to *Classes* in the full name *System.Classes*. As the uses contains *Classes*, the reference to *Classes.TThread* also succeeds.

In Unit2 the uses contains *System.Classes*. Therefore the reference *Classes.TThread* cannot be resolved anymore. Change it to *System.Classes.TThread* and it works.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I understand now. I never knew that about unit scope names!

Answer (score 9):

If you uses System.Classes you must also use System.Classes when referring to the classes unit in the code as shown below.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses System.Classes; // difference here

type TThread = class(System.Classes.TThread)
public
  property Terminated;
end;

implementation

end.
```

Comment: Uwe's answer arrived just a few seconds before yours.

Comment: Not really! Jan was about a minute faster.

Comment: I think Uwe's explanation is the best. So correct to mark his for best answer